# Values passed to controller change to null

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have come across this for the 1st time. I have passed a value from my view to controller, which generated an error. After placing breakpoints across the action that is retrieving it I found that the value is being retrieved but when passing from the post action to the get action it is changing to null. Any idea whats causing this?

My code as follows:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult reservation_step_1(string x)
    {
        string val = x;
        return RedirectToAction("reservation_step_2", "Home", new { val = val });
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult reservation_step_2(string val)
    {
        string rat = val;

        string a = rat.Substring(0, rat.Length - 16);
        string b = a.Substring(2);

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `x`?

Comment: x is the value being passed from the view, It is a value from a selected checkbox

Comment: The code you have shown works fine.

Comment: That seems very odd  as I have just tried it again. The value I tried with is "R 400.00<br />(per day)" This value varies but once I tried running it again it gave me a null error

Comment: You have invalid characters (the `<` and `>`) - and that is why I asked you want the value of `x` was :)

Comment: `<br />` itself is HTML tag, you should sanitize it first before passing as string parameter.

Comment: Even after removing invalid characters before passing to the controller I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments to the original post, it sounds like you need to add [ValidateInput(false)] to the reservation_step_2 method if you're passing HTML about.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I've tried that and there still seems to be no luck

Comment: Hmm, I'm running exactly what you've posted and the value is populated. Do you have any action filters or annotations on the controller?